# Why does the output_iterator Concept not require the output_iterator_tag?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

C++20 introduces proper Concepts for the different types of iterators in the standard library (input, output, forward, bidirectional, random access, ...).

While the original named requirements for those types did not mention [the iterator tags from `std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) at all, the new C++20 concepts explicitly require them. See for example the `input_iterator` Concept ([[iterator.concept.input]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.input)):

```
template<class I>
  concept input_iterator =
    input_or_output_iterator<I> &&
    indirectly_readable<I> &&
    requires { typename ITER_CONCEPT(I); } &&
    derived_from<ITER_CONCEPT(I), input_iterator_tag>;
```

Notice the check for the iterator tag in the last line. All the iterator concepts check for the respective tag like this, [except output iterator](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.output).
Output iterator has always been special in this regard, [since the early days of the Ranges TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/iterator/OutputIterator):

> Unlike the output iterator requirements in the C++ standard,
> OutputIterator in the Ranges TS does not require that the iterator
> category tag be defined.

What is the reason for this special treatment for output iterators?

Answer (score 4):

In C++20, iterator categories are in general detected automatically based on syntax. Explicitly use of the iterator tags are only used for opt-out or opt-in:

- everything weaker than `random_access_iterator_tag` is used to opt out of a stronger iterator category (for example, an input iterator might be syntactically indistinguishable from a forward iterator);
- `contiguous_iterator_tag` is used to opt into `contiguous_iterator`, since contiguity is a relative rare property that also can't be syntactically detected.

Output iterators have no need for this kind of fine-grained control - either you can or you can't write to it, and that's detected syntactically.

---

As to when opt-in/opt-out are provided, [Casey Carter explained](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/607#discussion_r392700693):

> - Passing an argument to a library component that constrains that argument is an implicit claim that the argument either doesn't satisfy
>   the constraint (doesn't meet the syntactic requirements) or that it
>   does model the constraint (meets the syntax and the semantic
>   requirements) so opt-in/opt-out are not generally necessary.
> - opt-in/opt-out facilities are only provided when we want to enable the library to assume that an argument that models some concept X
>   additionally models some refinement Y of X when it satisfies Y. (I've
>   been calling this "semantic promotion", but it's not a
>   well-established term.) The choice of opt-in vs. opt-out depends on
>   the expected frequency of false positives.

"Semantic promotion" is often done on non-output iterator arguments. Output iterators have nothing to be promoted to.

Comment: I'm not convinced by the opt-out argument yet. Forward, Bidirectional and RandomAccess all have different syntactic requirements that set them apart: Bidirectional does not have operators `+` and `+=`, forward does not have the `--` operators. Why would I need an additional mechanism if they are distinguishable by syntax? And further, even if there was a reason for opt-out when the syntactic requirements are met, why does that reason now not apply to output iterators as well?

Comment: "*also can't be syntactically detected*" Actually, C++20's contiguous_iterator concept has some things that you can syntactically key off of. Specifically, the function that converts an iterator into a pointer (`to_address` I believe it's called).

Comment: @ComicSansMS: "*why does that reason now not apply to output iterators as well*" Because `iterator` and `output_iterator` have detectable syntactic requirements. So a concept can mechanically detect one and prevent the other. This is not the case between `input_iterator` and `forward_iterator`; the differences between them are *all* semantic (what it means to copy one, etc).

Comment: @NicolBolas `to_address` works on anything with a `->` as long as you can form a `pointer_traits` specialization for it.